# Daily data generation and insertion

Tags: database, database-administration, data-generation

I'm facing a problem that perhaps someone around here can help me with.

I work in a business intelligence company and I'd like to simulate the whole usage cycle of our product the way our clients use it.

The short version is that our customers are inserting some 20 million records to their database on a daily basis, and our product crunches the new data at the end of the day.

I would like to automatically create around 20 million records and insert them into some database, everyday (MSSQL probably).

I should point out that the number of records should change from day to day between 15 to 25 million. Other than that, the data is supposed to be inserted to 6 tables linked with foreign keys.

I ususally use Redgate's SQL Generator to create data, but as far as I can tell it's good for one time data generation as opposed to the on going data generation I'm looking for.

If anyone knows of methods/tools adequate to this situation, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: You can't run it as a `cron` job (Linux/Unix) or a scheduled task (Windows)?

Comment: I could, but there are 2 problems. First, using the scheduler in windows means running SQL Generator from command line and appending  more rows to the database everyday (that's actually good..). Problem is that the generator doesn't check the primary key constraint and will create the same primary keys every day. Secondly, I don't know of a way to set the number of rows created each day to be random via the command line.

Comment: Generate the same PKs.. gack! There must be a way to make the product work properly, PK generation is the #1 requirement to insert data. As for randomizing the # of rows, I don't see that actually making a significant difference to processing or results? So, a nicety rather than a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a small Java (or similar) program to get the starting ID from the database, pick a random number of rows to insert, and then execute the data-generation tool as a child process.

For example, see Runtime.exec():

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

You can then run your program as a scheduled task or `cron` job.